# Retrieve public key by providing KeyID for encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle, gpgpu, public-key-encryption

Can I retrieve public key by providing keyID.( I have imported the public key using kleopatra)

Note:
I  am currently passing the public key file path to encrypt the stream.I am successfully encrypting the stream without any issues using BountyCastle nuget package.

I have tried this:

```
  PgpPublicKeyRingBundle bun = new PgpPublicKeyRingBundle(new byte[200]);
  var publicc = bun.GetPublicKey(long.Parse("12ERTY564"));
```

Update:
The above is test KeyID.

Comment: Is `new byte[200]` just for demo purposes or something?

Comment: new byte[200] is just for demo. I would like to know if we can achieve  this.

Comment: Well? What do you get as result? There is a `GetPublicKey` method that accepts a KeyID. The source code is there to be read. It's unlikely that the code does nothing. So what exactly is the question? Oh, uh, `"12ERTY564"` doesn't look like a `long` is that again for demo purposes or is this your actual problem?